# Is it possible to post data to ssl script from php?

Tags: php, ssl

Heres my situation:
Site A has form and it sends data through ssl to script. I want to bypass site A and send data directly to that script, but I don't know if ssl isn't a problem. Can someone help me out with this one?

Comment: It shouldn't be a problem: [php curl ssl](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=curl+ssl#hl=en&sugexp=frgbld&gs_nf=1&tok=qQ6WKj39h5p2x2BaXovx_Q&pq=curl%20ssl&cp=1&gs_id=4&xhr=t&q=php+curl+ssl&pf=p&sclient=psy-ab&oq=pcurl+ssl&aq=0c&aqi=g-c1g-b3&aql=&gs_l=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=87c6230bd8e448f1&biw=1600&bih=732)

Comment: You can do it if your version of PHP is built with SSL support.  Otherwise you could use `wget` or `curl` from the command line to make the request for you (assuming one of those two products was also built with SSL support).

Comment: Ok thx I just thought that  it requests some key that I don't have or something

Comment: @drew010, why not post your comment as an answer so that it can be voted on and accepted?

Answer (score 1):

Without some context, I'm taking a shot in the dark. But couldn't you just create your own form with the POST action to Site B's SSL?

Comment: Yes this would work, the browser will simply set up the tunnel when it performs the https request to the action page, whatever page that is. security measures might be in place to partially prevent this tough ( a unique token might be set on the form for example )